# Console.ReadLine() accept one char and stop prompt

Tags: c#, console.readline

In a console application,
I use a `Console.Readline()` to prompt,
It is only use to get an int (1 to 5),
However you can add more char than necessary.

How could I stop the prompt after record one char in my console please ?

You see this [underscore _](http://puu.sh/ekEZ7/7cba998fd7.png) .
I don't want to see it anymore.

*Edit 01/10/15 10pm :*

```
do
{
    string ChoixString = Console.ReadLine();
    Analyseur = int.TryParse(ChoixString, out ChoixInt);
} while (!Analyseur || ChoixInt <= 0 || ChoixInt >= 6);
```

Final goal : The user can't write more than one char in the prompt.

Solution :

```
ConsoleKeyInfo ChoixKey = Console.ReadKey();
string ChoixString = ChoixKey.Key.ToString();
Analyseur = int.TryParse(ChoixString, out ChoixInt);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You question is confusing: do you want to hide the cursor or stop reading after 1 character?

Comment: Probably hide the cursor. He can press Enter after entering one character, or he can even use the first character of a long inputted string.

Comment: I just want to allow the prompt and close it after entering one char and obviously hide the underscore of the prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

will read just one character/keypress

Comment: The solution isn't work "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ConsoleKeyInfo' to 'string'". Is there a solution with ReadLine because I need to do a TryParse after that..

Comment: Well, the ConsoleKeyInfo returned from ReadKey() contains the key pressed. Just read the docs...

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works however it is not obviously even with the doc. `ConsoleKeyInfo ChoixKey = Console.ReadKey();
string ChoixString = ChoixKey.Key.ToString();
Analyseur = int.TryParse(ChoixString, out ChoixInt);`